# Batch renaming files with pattern

Tags: bash, rename

I have some files named like these:

63018933.mp4?token=1325697436_b0c3e70c6e339380b4a484c576a8c287

63808488.mp4?token=1325697401_4ae5f7a68d93873c8881b303e7655e14

How do I rename all them to, for example 63018933.mp4(remove characters after mp4)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This could be one way:

```
for file in *.mp4\?token*; do mv --no-clobber "$file" "${file%%\?*}"; done
```

Comment: you might want to add -n or --no-clobber to mv   
if there's any chance that one of the mp4's might have the same name. Doesn't seem likely, but it costs nothing.

Answer (score 12):

If you have the `rename(1)` tool (which you do if you have Debian or a Debian-based Linux, including Ubuntu and derivatives):

```
rename -n 's/\.mp4.*$/.mp4/' *mp4*
```

Once you're convinced you have the right pattern, just remove the `-n` (dry-run) and let it run properly.

`rename(1)` will apply a Perl regular expression to the filenames given it.

Note that on most other Linux distributions, `rename` is a different file renaming program, which doesn't help for this particular renaming pattern.

Answer (score 5):

There is also mmv:

```
mmv -n "*.mp4*" "#1.mp4"
```

Remove the "-n" when output looks right.