# rename files in batch

Tags: rename

During importing my music files from backup (thanks to default naming scheme of `rhythmbox`), I have messed up the file names. Now the looks like:

```
00 - American Pie.ogg.ogg.ogg.ogg
00 - American Pie.ogg.ogg.ogg.ogg.ogg
00 - another brick in the wall.ogg.ogg.ogg.ogg
00 - another brick in the wall.ogg.ogg.ogg.ogg.ogg
00 - candle_in_the_wind.ogg.ogg.ogg.ogg
00 - candle_in_the_wind.ogg.ogg.ogg.ogg.ogg
```

While the file should look like

```
American Pie.ogg
another brick in the wall.ogg
candle_in_the_wind.ogg
```

And I have (as from `wc -l`) 3096 such files. How can I restore it in batch mode?
I have tried `rename` and `mmv` to work, as given in the ans of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28855/batch-renaming-files-with-pattern) question, but not working (problem with the `rename` syntax, and for `mmv`,there is collision).

Any help please?

Comment: What should be done when there is a collision? Should the files be overwritten or do you want to keep both versions?

Comment: files should be overwritten.

Answer (score 7):

Using perl-rename (which is one of the two tools that is commonly called `rename`; the other one uses a very different syntax and can't do this in one step):

```
rename -f 's/00 - ([^.]*).*/$1.ogg/' *.ogg
```

The `-f` or `--force` option makes rename overwrite any existing files.

The second part is a perl-style regular expression substitution. The basic syntax is `s/replacethis/withthis/` The pattern to match -- `00 - ([^.]*).*` -- will match all the *.ogg files with names like those in your question. `00 -` -- obviously, that just matches the pattern at the beginning of each of the filenames. `([^.]*)` is the meat of the regular expression. `[^.]` will match any single character that isn't a `.`, while `*` means 'any number of the previous thing', so `[^.]*` means 'any number of any characters that aren't `.`'. The parentheses mark out a capture group (more on that in a second). In regular expressions, `.` means 'any character' (if you want a literal dot on this side of the substitution you have to escape it, as in: `\.`), so the final `.*` means 'any number of any character'.

In the second part of the substitution command, `$1` means 'the first capture group' -- that is, that which is contained within the first pair of parentheses (see? Told you I'd come back to it). The `.ogg` means a literal '.ogg' -- on this side of the substitution, you *don't* need to escape the dot.

So, roughly translated into English, `'s/00 - ([^.]*).*/$1.ogg/'` is telling `rename` to 'take "00 - ", followed by (any number of characters that aren't a dot), then any number of characters; and replace that with the characters contained within the brackets and ".ogg."'.

On some systems, perl-rename is called `prename` (when `rename` is taken by the aforementioned other program). On some systems it isn't available at all :(

For recursiveness, you can do one of the following:

```
shopt -s globstar ## assuming your shell is bash
rename 's/00 - ([^.]*).*/$1.ogg/' **/*.ogg
```

Or:

```
find . -name '*.ogg' -exec rename 's/00 - ([^.]*).*/$1.ogg/' {} +
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
$ for f in *ogg; do 
   mv "$f" "$(printf "%s" "$f" | perl -lpe 's/^\d+ - (.*?).ogg.*/$1.ogg/')";
 done
```

To do this for all files, including those in subdirectories, either activate `globstar` if you're using bash:

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ for f in **/*ogg; do 
   mv "$f" "$(printf "%s" "$f" | perl -lpe 's/^\d+ - (.*?).ogg.*/$1.ogg/')";
 done
```

---

#### Explanation:

The funky stuff is being handled by perl. It is a simple regular expression that removes all numbers (`\d+`) followed by `-` (that's a dash with space on either side) from the beginning of the input string, matches everything until the fist `.ogg` and replaces eveything after that with the matched string (`$1`) and `.ogg`.

This could be expanded to the more cumbersome but more readable:

```
for f in *ogg; do 
   newname=$(printf "%s" "$f" | perl -lpe 's/^\d+ - (.*?).ogg.*/$1.ogg/')";
   mv "$f" "$newname";
 done
```

Comment: so, we have to remove 00- bit seperately, right?

Comment: @BaRud sorry, I completely missed that you wanted to remove that as well. See updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

A Bourne-compatible shell can do this without Perl or sed (but its aesthetic appeal is questionable...)

```
for f in *.ogg
do
    newfile="${f#00 - }"          ## Strip the leading "00 - "
    newfile="${newfile%%.ogg*}"   ## Strip .ogg and everything after
    newfile="${newfile}.ogg"      ## Append .ogg
    mv "$f" "$newfile"            ## Do the rename
done
```

Note that is also possible to use `ls -1 | while read f` to create the loop, but this construct would break in the event it encountered a filename with a newline character. Using the shell's standard globbing behaviour guards against this problem.

Comment: Why not `for f in *.ogg` rather than `ls -1 | while read f`? Apart from that, this is a good answer, probably what I'd do if my system didn't have (perl-)rename.

Comment: Mainly force of habit. I don't think there's any difference in behaviour in this case.

Comment: I think there is a difference on those edge cases where you have newlines in filenames. There's also probably a performance difference from that pipe, but that's not worth worrying about in practice.

Comment: As I said - no difference in this case. But yes, `ls -1 | while read f` would break on really funky filenames. I'll modify the answer to use the safer `for f in *.ogg`

Answer (score 1):

That's where Midnight Commander comes handy.  Select the files with "+" or "Insert".  Press F6 for rename.  Set mask to `*.ogg.ogg.ogg` and the destination to `*` and press Enter.  Sure, it's not automated, but it's still "in batch".

Comment: A typical #russianhacker :)
Привет, Павел!
Along those lines: krename.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1|while read f; do 
    newfile=$(echo $f|sed -e 's/\(\.ogg\)*$/.ogg/')
    mv "$f" "$newfile"
  done
```